# How can you create a GPO for two factor authentication?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, two-factor-authentication

i am new to Active Directorys and I was wondering wether you could create a GPO so that a choice of users has to submit a second layer of security, when others dont.

(This does not make perfect sense, I know)

If this is possible, could you let me know where I could find Information on how to build that GPO?

Comment: What MFA software/hardware is available on the target clients/devices?

Comment: There are multiple options. I am thinking of citrix ADC, miniorange, onespan or authlite.

Basically anything that is AD bindable and provides 2FA per mobile phone.

Comment: The policy settings you'll need to populate in the GPO will depend on which provider you're using and how you've deployed the requisite software/driver/extension on the endpoint. Pick one and their documentation will likely tell you how :)

Comment: I see. Thank you!